# I want to save data from variables into a XML file and coad it after restart of the programm

Tags: c#, xml, variables, save, load

I want to save the variables in a XML File and if i start the programm again i want to load the saved data into the programm/into the variables. How i can do that?
ATM the XML is created, but the data of the variables are always saved with "0,0".

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZOi6.jpg)

```
        double fixcosts = 0.0;
        double costs = 0.0;
        Maths math = new Maths();

        int month = DateTime.Today.Month;

        if (month == 1)
        {

            XDocument January_costs_categories = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                                                                new XElement("CostsCategories",
                                                                    new XElement("Fixcosts", fixcosts + " Euro"),
                                                                    new XElement("Costs", costs + " Euro")));


            Console.WriteLine("\n JANUARY COSTS \n");
            Console.WriteLine($"Fixcosts = {fixcosts}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Costs = {costs}");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nHow much you wanna add?");
            double howMuch = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            fixcosts = math.Addieren(fixcosts, howMuch);
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("\n JANUARY COSTS \n");
            Console.WriteLine($"Fixcosts = {fixcosts}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Costs = {costs}");



            January_costs_categories.Save(@"C:\Users\tobia\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\fixcosts_january.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any reason you chose XML and not json ?

Comment: Im new into coding .. i only know XML ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are create th XDocument before the variables have been assigned. Move the line with `new XDocument(...` to just before you call `Save()`.

Comment: Oh.. okay. It worked... i dont understand why this version is right.. but it worked...

Comment: Which Command i have to use to load the data into the programm?

Comment: In your original version the value of fixcosts was still 0 when you created the document. Only after `fixcosts = math.Addieren(fixcosts, howMuch);` would the value be set to something else. This is even observable with your programm output. Before the user enters data the values are 0. fixcost is of type `double` which is a value type. You should read about the difference of value types and reference types.

Comment: About loading: The XDocument class should have a method `Load()` for that.